# How many people died at the Tulsa Race Riot?

Tags: history, united-states

There is a video on Facebook by the Young Turks that claims 3000 black people were killed by the KKK, but there is a text "UPDATE" under the video that corrects it to 300. Other [sources](http://tulsahistory.org/learn/online-exhibits/the-tulsa-race-riot/) I saw online agree with this updated number.

BUT, there is [another video](http://atlantablackstar.com/2014/09/12/before-911-the-terrorist-plane-attack-against-black-people-america-doesnt-talk-about/) I had seen before where a black commentator on Fox tells a white commentator that up to 4000 blacks were killed in an aerial attack.

I'd like to know the the historically accepted number.

Comment: @Oddthinking There's a new topic on meta now, to [discuss this question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3186/2703).

Comment: I've reverted your question back to the initial revision and clarified what is intended by "truth". Hopefully you will find this acceptable so we can reopen.